# Can't match '£' (pound sterling) in javascript regex

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm applying this regex expression:

```
a = new window.RegExp('(£...)');
```

To the responsetext of an XMLHttprequest:

```
d= a.exec(Xml.responseText);
```

where 'Xml.responseText' is a string containing the html source of the following page:

```
http://www.amazon.co.uk/gp/aw/d/B0050IIVNK
```

Up to now I've been able to match any expression in this page with no problem at all with the same code. But when it comes to match the character '£', 'd' becomes 'null' (and it shouldn't because there are at least two of theese characters in the page.

does anybody know why this is happening?

thanks.

EDIT: Solved the problem by searching for the encoded value \xa3 as suggested by MelanciaUK, thank you.

Comment: Did you try to search for the encoded value instead of the symbol?

Comment: Are you sure that you can access the `responseText` from amazon? Sounds like a same-origin-policy problem

Comment: This is a chrome extension, I've set up all the permissions for amazon.

Comment: I'll try your point Melancia

Comment: Maybe helpful: `encodeURIComponent('£'); "%C2%A3"` also, `'£'.charCodeAt(0); // 163` so you might want `&#163;` too. Furthermore `&pound;` is a _character entity_ in HTML.

Answer (score 0):

The issue does not come from your regex, you can check it yourself with a static string :

```
a = new window.RegExp('£...');
d= a.exec("This ring costs £205.50 but I only can spend £150 today.");
// ["£205"]
```

But I would use a better one to retrieve amounts :

```
/*
    (
        £         # £ symbol
        \d+       # followed by 1+ number
        (?:       # non-captured group
            \.    # a dot
            \d+   # followed by 1+ number, for decimals
        )?        # decimals are optional
    )
*/
var regex = /(£\d+(?:\.\d+)?)/g;
var input = "This ring costs £205.50 but I only can spend £150 today.";

console.log(input.match(regex)); //["£205.50", "£150"]
```

*EDIT : changed for a regex literal for readability, following Bergi advice*

Comment: Why not use a regex literal?

Comment: I followed the original example. Does using RegExp object affect prefs ?